# Dynamically sum 2 fields on an MVC Edit form

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC Edit form with 2 fields called ExVAT and VAT. I want to add another field with the total of these 2 values.

At the moment what I have shows the total of the 2 fields when the form is loaded. But if you were to change one of the other fields the total is not updated to reflect the new total.

So for example in the screen shot below:

[image]

I have changed the Ex.Vat Figure from 22 to 32, but the total has not been updated (I'll deal with formatting when the value is correct)

The code to get the total is:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Vat + Model.ExVat)
```

What is the best way to make the total field update as the other fields are edited?

Comment: You can add `keypress` JS event and recalculate accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3tnjtLv5/1/

```
<div>
    <div><input id="txtA" type="text" value="1"></div>
    <div><input id="txtB" type="text" value="2"></div>
    <div id="txtResult">
</div>

<script>
    var txtA=$('#txtA');
    var txtB=$('#txtB');
    var txtResult=$('#txtResult');

    function updateSum() {
      txtResult.html(parseInt(txtA.val()) + parseInt(txtB.val()));
    }

    $(function() {
      updateSum();
      txtA.change('change', updateSum);
      txtB.bind('change', updateSum);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery input, property change method

```
jQuery('#Ex.vat', '#vat').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
$('#Total').val($('#Ex.vat').val()+$('#vat').val());
```

});